# How to update the cross reference table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF cross reference tables are abstracted away by creating many-to-many relationships.  E.G.

[image]

There's a SQL table `dbo.TrialContactCrossReference` that relates TrialContactId to TrialID.  Now, EF did not generate an Entity `TrialContactCrossReference` because it went with this MANY-MANY relationship thing.  How do I add a new row to said table?

I tried

`context.TrialContacts.???` and `context.ClinicalTrials.???` and just don't know what to do with this.  If I have a new Contact that I want to relate to a trial how am I supposed to go about it?

Comment: This is a tiny tiny picture with huge huge white space around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trick that was not obvious to me when setting this up.  TableA must be added to TableB, not just to itself.  In fact, looking at the generated entities each entity has a List<> of the other entity.

```
class TableA
{
   List<TableB> TableB;
}

class TableB
{
   List<TableA> TableA;
}
```

For example, if I want to add a TrialContact to a ClinicalTrial then I write:

`context.ClinicalTrials.TrialContacts.Add(trialContact);`
`context.SaveChanges()`

Then the xRef table be updated to reflect the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a new Contact that I want to relate to a trial how am I supposed to go about it?

Assuming you have an existing Contact instance just do:

```
trial.TrialContacts.Add(contact);
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF will take care of the intermediate table insert for you.  Note that adding `Contact`s and `Trial`s works the same as if they weren't related.

Comment: This answer was helpful.  Ultimately I had to do something more like `context.ClinicalTrials.TrialContacts.Add(trialContact);`.  I had to include both tables.

Answer (score 2):

trial.Contacts.Add(contact);

OR

contact.Trials.Add(trial);

OR (and my advise)

you could create an additional entity for cross reference table. this will convert many-many to 2 one-many relationships. more then %90 cases crosstables has additional columns (at least IsActive, RecordDate etc.)  even it doesnt, it may be so in future and it requires you make lots of changes in code.